# How to set different tint color for leftBarButtonItem and rightBarButtonItem in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, iphone, applet

I have tried many solutions but it’s not working as expected

As per my application structure in every viewcontoller viewWillDisappear we have to restore navigation bar like below code

```
let textAttributes = [NSAttributedString.Key.foregroundColor: UIColor.black]
        navigationController?.navigationBar.tintColor = .blue
        navigationController?.navigationBar.backgroundColor = .white
        navigationController?.navigationBar.isTranslucent = false

        // Restore the navigation bar to default from transparent
        if #available(iOS 15, *) {
            let appearance = UINavigationBarAppearance()
            appearance.configureWithDefaultBackground()
            appearance.backgroundColor = .white 
            appearance.titleTextAttributes = textAttributes

            // Customizing our navigation bar
            navigationItem.standardAppearance = appearance
            navigationItem.scrollEdgeAppearance = appearance
        } else {
            navigationController?.navigationBar.titleTextAttributes = textAttributes
            navigationController?.navigationBar.setBackgroundImage(nil, for: .default)
            navigationController?.navigationBar.shadowImage = nil
        }
```

and in other viewcontroller i need to add **leftBarButtonItem** and **rightBarButtonItem** with different colors but it always comes blue only when i change above code **navigationBar.tinitColor** i can able to see the color changes in navigationItem barbutton but both are same color which is what i give in **navigationBar.tinitColor**

this is  rightBarButtonItem tint color change code

```
let barButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(title: "", style: .plain, target: self, action: nil)
        barButtonItem.tintColor = .black
        barButtonItem.accessibilityIdentifier = "navbar_notificationbutton"
        navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = barButtonItem
```

Actual Result screenshot

[image: Actual Result screenshot]

Expected Result screenshot

[image: Expected Result screenshot]

Thanks in Advance!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To change or apply different tint color for the navigation bar buttons you can use the below code

```
    let backButton = UIButton(frame: CGRect(x: 0.0, y: 0.0, width: 44.0, height: 44.0))
    backButton.setImage(UIImage(systemName: "chevron.backward"), for: .normal)
    backButton.addTarget(self, action: #selector(btnBack), for: .touchUpInside)
    backButton.tintColor = .red
    self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(customView: backButton)
    
    let notificationButton = UIButton(frame: CGRect(x: 0.0, y: 0.0, width: 44.0, height: 44.0))
    notificationButton.setImage(UIImage(systemName: "bell"), for: .normal)
    notificationButton.addTarget(self, action: #selector(btnShowNotifications), for: .touchUpInside)
    notificationButton.tintColor = .systemGreen
    self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(customView: notificationButton)
```

In the above code, I created a `back` button and assigned it to `leftBarButtonItem`, and similarly, I created another button with different tint color and assigned it to `rightBarButtonItem`.